# Extract a value from a web page response

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the price [image]

I tried the below code, and it failed to extract the required parameter value.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.westernunion.com/us/en/web/send-money/start?SrcCode=12345&ReceiveCountry=IN&SendAmount=100&ISOCurrency=CNY&FundsOut=BA&FundsIn=CreditCard'
page = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
price = soup.select('.smoExchangeRate')
print(price)
```

Comment: Does that page use javascript to dynamically build the page content?  requests doesn't do javascript.

Comment: Looks like the page is built using some sort of JavaScript framework. I would look into using Selenium.

Comment: As @JohnGordon said, Requests doesn't render the page so you will probably need to use `Selenium ` to render before parsing with bs4.

Answer (score 2):

If you download the HTML to a file, and try to search for `smoExchangeRate`, you'll notice there's no result. That's because the element on the page with the given class is created by JavaScript, and not by pure HTML.

If you MUST use this site to get this data, you need to throw the HTML into a renderer, and then extract the resulting HTML after JavaScript is ran.

If you don't though, I would recommend searching for a currency API to get this kind of value, since doing it with the renderer approach is prone to failure depending on the implementation.

Edit: Seems like the page domain (Western Union) has an API: https://developer.westernunion.com/

You probably wanna check that, since it will return data that is 'consumable' by apps.

Comment: Its not just the class. I looked into it and the entire page is rendered using JavaScript. Must be one of the frameworks.

Comment: Yep, not even the strings definitions are there, so not even a simple renderer with JS support would work, it would need to be a full browser, doing multiple requests for external scripts.